# Touching a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am querying a bunch of tables/models to generate a list of `tab_projects` IDs and use those IDs to do stuff to other records in other tables/models, but I do want to update the projects that are affected by the query. This is what I have so far:

```
_account_type_list_member_id = RefAccountType.find_by_typename('List Member').id

# Select all projects more than one week old and associated accounts not classified as a list member
_records = TabProject
               .select('tab_projects.id as tab_project_id, tab_projects.name as project_name, tab_projects.tab_client_seat_id as client_seat_id, tab_clients.name as client_name, tab_accounts.screen_name')
               .where("tab_projects.updated_at < '#{1.week.ago}' and tab_client_project_accounts.ref_account_type_id != #{_account_type_list_member_id}")
               .joins('inner join tab_clients on tab_projects.tab_client_id = tab_clients.id')
               .joins('inner join tab_client_project_accounts on tab_projects.id = tab_client_project_accounts.tab_project_id')
               .joins('inner join tab_accounts on tab_client_project_accounts.tab_account_id = tab_accounts.id')

# loop through all records in recordset
_records.map do |_record| 
    # do some stuff
end

_records.touch
```

When I run it I get the following error:

`'method_missing': undefined method 'touch' for #<TabProject::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000000084b2a00> (NoMethodError)`

So my questions are:

1. How can I `touch` the `updated_at` for the records returned from the query and saved into `_records`?
2. Is there some way I can `touch` all the records involved? It'd have to be records spread across `tab_projects` (the original table/model), `tab_client_project_accounts` (the join table), and `tab_accounts` (accounts affiliated with any given records in `tab_projects`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call the `touch` method on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` Proxy, basically `ActiveRecord::Relation` is a layer on top of Array so you will need to call it

```
_records.each(&:touch)
```

Touch will just update `updated_at` to `Time.current` so you can implement this yourself using the very performant `update_all`, this will generate a database update statement that works on multiple records

```
_records.update_all(update_at: Time.current)
```

You can call `update_all` on an `ActiveRecord::Collection` Proxy, for all available methods see the docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Polymorphic+Associations